# Prepend string to a file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

My `js` lives inside a `FF addon` so has access to prilivaged `api`. Currently I'm able to append a string to a file or truncate a file and write the `string`.

But is there an easy way to prepend a `string` to a file? So my `string` is placed at the beginning of file, then existing content follows.

#### new file

```
FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file, FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY | FileUtils.MODE_CREATE | FileUtils.MODE_TRUNCATE)
```

#### append to file

```
FileUtils.openFileOutputStream(file, FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY | FileUtils.MODE_APPEND)
```

`main.js` contents ..

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var filename = 'test.txt',
    ostream,
    string = 'test content',
    file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath('/home/user/');
    file.append(fileName);

try {

    if (file.exists() === false) {
        file.create(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 420);
    }

    ostream = FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file, FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY | FileUtils.MODE_CREATE | FileUtils.MODE_TRUNCATE);
    var converter = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
    converter.charset = "UTF-8";
    var istream = converter.convertToInputStream(combinedString);

    NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function (status) {

        if (!components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
            console.log('success: ' + file.path);
        } else {
            console.log('error: ' + file.path);
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the effect you're trying to achieve? Why not create an event listener for the different reasons one might be called instead of the other and simply call it in the listener?

Comment: I'm providing various methods for adding text to a file e.g truncate, prepend and append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `OS.File` in the end, reading file contents, prepending string to data then writing combined data back to file ..

```
let promise = OS.File.read(filePath);
promise = promise.then(function onSuccess(contents) {
  let text = new TextDecoder().decode(contents);

  combinedString = combinedString + '\n\n' + text;

  if (System.getPlatform().indexOf('win') >= 0)
        combinedString = combinedString.replace(/[\n]/g, '\r\n');

  let encodedArray = new TextEncoder().encode(combinedString);

  var promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(filePath, encodedArray);
  promise.then(
    function() {
      console.log('success');
    },
    function(ex) {
      console.log('error');
    }
  );
  return true;
}, 
function onError(reason) {
  if (System.getPlatform().indexOf('win') >= 0)
    combinedString = combinedString.replace(/[\n]/g, '\r\n');
    let encodedArray = new TextEncoder().encode(combinedString);
    if (reason.becauseNoSuchFile()) {
      var promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(filePath, encodedArray);
      promise.then(
         function() {
          console.log('success');
        },
        function(ex) {
          console.log('error');
        }
      );
    return false;
  }
});
```